# Can an iOS "Developer" Role create/upload Testflight builds?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

I've outsourced the development for one project and I gave them the "Developer Role" and "Access to Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles."

They're working on a test build and getting ready for a distributable version to show me, but they are insisting on me granting them Admin priviledges which I refuse.

After a lot of angry arguing back and forth they continue to insist on admin rights claiming they can't proceed without it.

So far, I've created a development profile and the App ID on the store.

I'm trying my best to understand the documentation and all the different provisioning profiles and certificates, the only bottleneck that I can see is that maybe they need a distribution profile.

However, the only way to create a distribution profile is to upload a CSR file which they recommend being done through Xcode directly. They insist that they don't have access.

Where is the gap in communication there and what are the steps we're missing for them to be able to ad-hoc or testflight distribute?

I absolutely refuse to grant Admin rights and cannot believe Apple hasn't already accounted for contract workers to make User Roles friendly enough to accommodate a situation like this.

My understanding from the documentation is that once they were granted "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" they should be able to do everything they need

Answer (score 18):

You can check all the permissions that every role has in [Program Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/) page.

To upload a TestFlight build you need:

- a `Distribution` signing Certificate (with the private key) and
- an `App Store` Provisioning Profile.

***Apple Developer Website***: While accounts with `Developer` access can **download** all type of Provisioning Profiles and Certificates (only public keys though) can only **create** `Development` Provisioning Profiles and Certificates.

***App Store Connect***: Accounts with `Developer` access, can **manage** and **upload** TestFlight builds but cannot **create** a **new application** nor a **new version** for an already existing application

So, if a new version of the app has already been created in *App Store Connect*, you as an Admin, can create the missing parts in *Apple Developer Website* (Certificate and Provisioning Profile) send them to the Developer team (account with `Developer` access) and they will be able to upload a TestFlight build with their account.

Except `Admin`, `App Manager` is a role that have all the necessary permissions to create a new version for an app as well as create `Distribution` Certificates and `App Store` Provisioning Profiles.

Note: All roles, except `Account Holder` and `Admin`, can be limited to specific applications but only in *App Store Connect*.